# grep excluding superstrings

Tags: git, grep

I am trying to use git grep to search for patterns, excluding superpatterns.

My specific example is:

```
git grep 'ad'
```

But I want to exclude all patterns like "load" and 'Load' and "Thread' and 'thread(self)' , etc, etc, etc. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Use `-w` option: `git grep -w ad`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be an answer @codeforester ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your further requests, if you want to still match certain words, but not all of them, you can exclude a word (or list of words) by some of the following ways:

### Whole Words

As was answered previously, matching whole words will match a pattern that is contained in a "word" unit.  These word units are letters, numbers, and underscore.  `-w` is the option for that:

`git grep -w ad` will only find instances of the word "ad", but not "load" or "toad", etc.

### Invert-Match

Another option is to re-pipe grep to itself, and use the inverse-match flag.  Let's say you want to find instances of "ad", and all words that contain "ad" with the exception of "toad" and "load".  You can pipe grep to another grep command using `-v` and giving the list of words you want to exclude using an escaped pipe (`|`)as the separator:

`git grep ad | grep -v "toad\|load"`

or if you're using regex:

`git grep ad | grep -ve "toad|load"`

If you still want the `more` type action, you can pipe the last bit to `more`.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by [@codeforester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6862601/codeforester) in the comments section.

```
git grep -w ad
```

Let me expand and explain what it means.

> **git grep**
>   **-w / --word-regexp**
>
> Match the pattern **only at word boundary** (either begin at the beginning of a line,
>   or preceded by a non-word character; end at the end of a line or followed by a non-word character).

Adding the `-w` will search for the whole word and not part of it, it means that the pattern must match the whole text and not only part of it.

---

From the unix grep man page:

> Select **only those** lines containing  matches that **form whole words**.
>     The  test is that the matching substring must either be
>     at the  beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word
>     constituent character.Similarly, it must be either at the end
>     of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.
>     Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and  the
>     underscore.

Comment: How would I go about searching for anything containing "oad" but not "load" or "toad?

Comment: using regular expression with the required values

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind providing an example so this is 100% clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-w` option to have it search only on words.  This applies to standard grep as well as most greplike tools.

Comment: That works thanks. But out of interest, how can I exclude words more generally?